# Why does the email code not working after hosting on iis

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I have written a simple email sending code which works when I run it locally from Visual Studio but when I host the website it throws an Exception:-

> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 40.100.137.82:587 at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot,
>   SocketAddress socketAddress) at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure,
>   Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address,
>   ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception&
>   exception) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream,
>   Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket,
>   Socket& abortSocket6) at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object
>   owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject,
>   GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint
>   servicePoint) at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() at
>   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)

```
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");

            client.Port = 587;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(sender, password);
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Credentials = credentials;

            try
            {
                var mail = new MailMessage(sender.Trim(), recipient.Trim());
                mail.Subject = "Password Reset OTP";
                Random random = new Random();
                otp = random.Next(100000, 999999).ToString();
                mail.Body = otp;
                client.Send(mail);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ViewBag.message = e.InnerException;
            }
```

Comment: What user account is your application pool running under in IIS?

Comment: @mjwills it is running under DefaultAppPool with Integrated Pipeline Mode and .net CLR Version is 4.0.

Comment: What is the `Identity` of that app pool (under `Advanced Settings`)?

Comment: it is system name\username, user has admin rights.

Comment: So it is a local account? It likely lacks network access.

Comment: @mjwills it has Internet connection